# Why doesn't $AA^-A=A \Rightarrow A^-AA^-=A^-$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

The condition for being a generalized inverse matrix is $AA^-A=A$.

There's another condition $A^-AA^-=A^-$, and when this also holds, $A^-$ is called a reflexive inverse.

But when does it happen that only the first of these conditions holds? Doesn't the first condition imply the second?

Comment: "Doesn't the first condition imply the second?" You may want to elaborate on how the first condition implies the second one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $A^{-}=I$.  This satisfies the first condition but not the second.

Comment: An easier counterexample can be obtained by choosing $A=0$.

Comment: @user1551 Fair point, though I reached my example by thinking about breaking $A$ into an intervtible part and non-invertible part, and I think one can show that is the key issue.  While one can completely remove having an invertible part, I think it makes the the generalized inverse more confusing.